# Pandas: within groupby groups, return max value if it is at least 3x greater than any other value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to group a dataframe by the `FeatureID` column, and then test each group to determine if the max value in the group's `gene_count` column is at least 3 times greater than any of the other `gene_count` values in the group.

If no value is at least 3x times greater, I need to return the row with the max value in the `feature_div` column.

At this point, if there is not a row with max `gene_count` (aka they are all tied) and no row with max `feature_div`, then that `FeatureID` should not be returned.

So the pseudocode logic is:

```
For each group in df.groupby("FeatureID"):
    If max(gene_count) 3x > all other gene_counts in group:
        return this row
    Elif:
        there is a max(feature_div) return this row
    Else:
        max(gene_count) is not >3 x higher than all other gene_counts in group
        and the feature_div scores are all tied
        pass
```

Here is my dataframe:

```
FeatureID     gene      feature_div  gene_count
1_1001_1028   NTRK1.1        2         2.0
1_1001_1028   TP53.1         1         2.0
1_1001_193    MTOR.1         1         9.0
1_1001_193    TP53.2         1         3.0
1_1003_1034   EGFR.1         3         4.0
1_1003_1034   EGFR.5         3         4.0
1_1008_823    ABL1.1         1         2.0
1_1008_823    BRCA2.2        2         2.0
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
 FeatureID     gene      feature_div    gene_count
 1_1001_1028   NTRK1.1       2           2.0
 1_1001_193    MTOR.1        1           9.0
 1_1008_823    BRCA2.2       2           2.0
```

In the first row, NTRK1.1 gets selected because the counts are tied, but it has higher `feature_div` than TP53.1.

In the second row, MTOR.1 gets selected because the `gene_count` is 3x higher than TP53.3.

In the third row BRCA2.2 is selected because the `gene_count` are tied but it has higher `feature_div`.

1_1003_1034 is not returned because the `gene_count` is not 3 times higher than the other options, and there is no `feature_div` higher than the other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses `apply` and a custom filtering function to solve this:

```
def filter_function(x):
    max_gene_counts = x.sort_values('gene_count', ascending=False).gene_count.head(2).values
    max_feature_divs = x.sort_values('feature_div', ascending=False).feature_div.head(2).values

    if max_gene_counts[0] >= 3 * max_gene_counts[1]:
        return x[x.gene_count == max_gene_counts[0]]
    elif max_feature_divs[0] > max_feature_divs[1]:
        return x[x.feature_div == max_feature_divs[0]]
    else:
        pass

df.groupby('FeatureID').apply(filter_function)
```

Result:

```
  FeatureID      gene  feature_div  gene_count
1_1001_1028   NTRK1.1            2         2.0
 1_1001_193    MTOR.1            1         9.0
 1_1008_823   BRCA2.2            2         2.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Also, thanks for editing the formatting on the comments.

Comment: @SummerEla: No problems, happy to help :)